# Some events unprocessed by Kafka Streams application on Kubernetes on bare metal when broker fails

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My KStreams application has three instances running as a deployment on kubernetes cluster.
There are two input topics - one 'state' topic and one 'update-state' topic. The state topic is read as a `GlobalKTable` and the update-state topic is read as KStream and joined to the GKTable.
When an update-state event arrives, the state is updated and written to the state topic.

The Streams config includes 'exactly_once' processing (full config below) with the expectation that 'update-state' events won't be lost/duplicated even in the case of failures. I have tested this under load and have verified that it works when application instances fail (pod deleted). There is some lag introduced as consumers are rebalanced at failure and when the new instance is available, but that's ok as long as events are eventually processed.

However, when a broker fails, some events on the update-state topic are left unprocessed. This happens at the time of the broker failure and also when a leader imbalance check is done after the broker is restarted.

**Two questions** -

1. Should 'exactly-once' cover the case of a broker failure? (My
   understanding is that it should)
2. If so, what configurations are
       necessary to guarantee that events cannot be left unprocessed on the
       input topic?

Application Kafka version: 1.0.2
Broker Kafka version: 1.0.0 (deployed using Helm chart https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/kafka )

Broker Config

```
log.dirs=/opt/kafka/data/logs
transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms=10000
min.insync.replicas=2
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
broker.id=0
default.replication.factor=3
heap.opts=-Xmx1G -Xms1G
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=16000
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:31090
request.timeout.ms=2000
jmx.port=5555
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.244.3.91:9092,EXTERNAL://my.domain:31090
leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=60
zookeeper.connect=kafka-zookeeper:2181
```

Streams Config:

```
application.id = update-state
application.server =
bootstrap.servers = [kafka:9092]
buffered.records.per.partition = 1000
cache.max.bytes.buffering = 10485760
client.id =
commit.interval.ms = 100
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.deserialization.exception.handler = class org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndFailExceptionHandler
default.key.serde = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$ByteArraySerde
default.timestamp.extractor = class org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.FailOnInvalidTimestamp
default.value.serde = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$ByteArraySerde
key.serde = null
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
num.standby.replicas = 1
num.stream.threads = 2
partition.grouper = class org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.DefaultPartitionGrouper
poll.ms = 100
processing.guarantee = exactly_once
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
replication.factor = 2
request.timeout.ms = 40000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
rocksdb.config.setter = null
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
state.cleanup.delay.ms = 600000
state.dir = /tmp/kafka-streams
timestamp.extractor = null
upgrade.from = null
value.serde = null
windowstore.changelog.additional.retention.ms = 86400000
zookeeper.connect =
```

Consumer Config:

```
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
auto.offset.reset = earliest
bootstrap.servers = [kafka:9092]
check.crcs = true
client.id = update-state-9e713a1a-3ee1-4abc-8b42-36e203cdb468-StreamThread-1-consumer
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
enable.auto.commit = false
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = update-state
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
interceptor.classes = null
internal.leave.group.on.close = false
isolation.level = read_committed
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
max.poll.interval.ms = 2147483647
max.poll.records = 1000
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamPartitionAssignor]
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 305000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
session.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

Producer Config:

```
acks = all
batch.size = 16384
bootstrap.servers = [kafka:9092]
buffer.memory = 33554432
client.id = update-state-9e713a1a-3ee1-4abc-8b42-36e203cdb468-StreamThread-2-0_2-producer
compression.type = none
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
enable.idempotence = true
interceptor.classes = null
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
linger.ms = 100
max.block.ms = 60000
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1
max.request.size = 1048576
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retries = 2147483647
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
transaction.timeout.ms = 1500
transactional.id = update-state-0_2
value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

Comment: Yes, broker failure should be handled correctly. Not sure atm, but could you try out Kafka Streams version 2.1? We fixed some bugs. Also, there is no Broker version `2.11` -- this sounds like the Scala version you broker code is build for, but it's not a Kafka version.

Comment: Thanks for the response @MatthiasJ.Sax. It's that 'handled correctly' part that I'm trying to get a handle on. Is this something that can be done by configuration settings alone, or is it something that would have to be handled in the application code using exception handlers perhaps? I will update my Streams version as you suggest and try again (and get the correct broker version). The number of possible configuration combinations is pretty big. Any help on narrowing down which configs to focus on would be helpful.

Comment: Broker version is 1.0.0. 2.11 does indeed refer to the scala version.

Comment: Setting `exactly_once` should be sufficient to get what you want -- no need for code changes or other setting. For broker/topic setting, you need `replication.factor=3` and `min.insync.replicas=2` -- for internal created topics, ii might be required to set those manually. Can you double check those config for all topics Kafka Streams creates?

Comment: I updated Kafka Streams version to 2.1 - I still see events left unprocessed  on the 'update-state' topic. 
I updated the broker version to 2.0.1 and see the same. 
I double checked all of the topics to make sure replication.factor=3 and min.insync.replicas=2.
__consumer_offsets is the only one I can see that doesn't have min.insync.replicas explicitly set, nor can I see a configuration parameter for it at the broker level.
Is there something I should be watching for in logs?

Comment: Of note, but probably unrelated, since I upgraded versions I see the Kafka Streams application loses connection to the broker about two minutes after the broker failure.My guess is this happens around a leader imbalance check. 
    leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=120

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you elaborate how "some events on the update-state topic are left unprocessed" manifests? Can you give a minimum example of input records, expected behavior and observed result? I try to understand the details of the use case? Because `GlobalKTable` is different and not part of regular transactions, the observed behavior might be expected -- but I am not sure atm. Note that GlobalKTables introduce asyn and non-deterministic behavior -- this is unrelated to EOS, and EOS does only work if the computation is deterministic what might not be the case of your example

Comment: So, for my test case I push 50,000 json messages (10k per min) to the 'state' topic (to be read as GlobalKTable). These messages have unique numerical keys. Each message contains a field 'state:PENDING'
After this I push 50,000 events with the same set of keys to the 'update-state' topic. The Streams topology joins this stream to the GlobalKTable, updates the message to contain 'state:PROCESSED' and writes it to the 'state' topic. The state topic is compacted.
During broker failure, I see no 'state:PROCESSED' message for a few keys although messages for those keys exist on 'update-state'

Comment: I hope that makes sense. My understanding is that although a transaction might have rolled back for the unprocessed events due to broker unavailability, it would be re-read on the next poll and tried again. Does that sound right?

Comment: Thanks for the details. Makes sense. Sound like this should work. Would you mind filing a bug report with all the details, so we can reproduce and fix the issue. It's unclear to me atm, if it might be a broker or stream issue.

Comment: Thanks again for looking into this @MatthiasJ.Sax. I've opened this bug to track - https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7716 .